# what & character in class mean?

Tags: c++, class

```
Date &Date::operator++() // what **&** mean? i know what this character mean in pointers, but here i'm not sure
{
 helpIncrement(); 
 return *this; 
} 

Date Date::operator++( int ) // 
{
 Date temp = *this; 
 helpIncrement();

 return temp; 
}
```

Thank you very much! I don't know what else to say so I just put some text here to provide full question

Comment: That you returning a reference to the Date object.

Comment: @rtn2020  It seems it is the ampersand.

Comment: Note that `Date &Date::...` is the same as `Date& Date::..` or `Date & Date::...`.

Comment: @DanielLangr thank you, sir! And to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning a reference of Date object.
By returning *this you convert pointer of this object to reference